# Passing opened file as argument in C

Tags: c, file

I get the error

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

in line `fread(&libro, sizeof(struct Libro), 1, archivo);`

When I run the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void abrirArchivo(FILE *archivo);
void cerrarArchivo(FILE *archivo);
void listar(FILE *archivo);

struct Libro {
   char isbn[ 13 ];     /* número de libro */
   char nombre[ 30 ];   /* nombre de libro */
   char autor[ 30 ];    /* nombre del autos */
   int edicion;         /* edicion */ 
};

FILE *archivo;     /* archivo = puntero al archivo clientes.dat */

int main()
{
    abrirArchivo(archivo);
    listar(archivo);
    cerrarArchivo(archivo);

    return 0; /* indica terminación exitosa */
}

void abrirArchivo(FILE *archivo){
    if ( ( archivo = fopen( "libros.dat", "rb" ) ) == NULL ) {
       printf( "El archivo no pudo abrirse" );
    }
}

void cerrarArchivo(FILE *archivo){
    fclose(archivo);
}

void listar(FILE *archivo){
    struct Libro libro;

    printf("ISBN\tNombre\tAutor\tEdicion\n");

    fread(&libro, sizeof(struct Libro), 1, archivo);

    while(!feof(archivo)){
        printf("%s\t\t%s\t\t%s\t%d\n", libro.isbn, libro.nombre, libro.autor, libro.edicion);
        fread(&libro, sizeof(struct Libro), 1, archivo);
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `archivo` is not going to change as a result of `abrirArchivo`. If you want it to change, pass `&archivo` instead, and change the function accordingly.

Comment: Function arguments are essentially local variables.  Any changes you make to them are not visible to the caller.  If you want the caller to see the new value, you have to pass the address of the variable, and the function needs to write to the target of that pointer.

Comment: Why do you use a global variable **and** a function argument? Why do they have the same name (this is called "shadowing")? Do you know which one you're using inside the function (hint: the function argument)?

Answer (score 7):

```
FILE *archivo;     /* archivo = puntero al archivo clientes.dat */

[...]

void abrirArchivo(FILE *archivo){
    if ( ( archivo = fopen( "libros.dat", "rb" ) ) == NULL ) {
       printf( "El archivo no pudo abrirse" );
    }
}
```

In this function, the *parameter* `archivo` **shadows** the variable `archivo` in file scope, it's a different variable. When calling this, you pass the global `archivo`, but the function receives a copy of it and assigns to the copy (the local `archivo`) which doesn't exist any more when the function exits.

Simple solution: remove the argument from that function altogether. Slightly better: Make it **return** the `FILE *` it opened and don't take a parameter.

---

Side notes:

- Compile with enough warnings enabled (e.g. for `gcc` use `-std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic`). A good compiler should warn you about shadowing of variables.
- Write your code **in english**. Sooner or later, you'll show it someone who doesn't speak your language (like you do here) and understanding the semantics of identifiers helps a lot with understanding the code.

Comment: I disagree with the 'choice of language' comment.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler are you saying you think it's a good idea to use identifiers in a language other than english?

Comment: Yes; if the code is being written for Italians to read and use, it's fine to use Italian.  If the code is being written for the the English to use, use English (colour, behaviour).  If it's for Americans to use, maybe you convert to American (a different language; heck, the Americans even use a different alphabet from the English — aye-zee versus aye-zed!)  If the audience for the code (as opposed to the question on SO) is international, then company/team dynamics will control the language used, but often American will be appropriate.  But I don't think such comments are warranted here.

Comment: Obviously, this is IMO — In MY Opinion.  Your mileage may vary.  I didn't want to make a mountain out of a molehill, but I dislike what might be perceived as the arrogance that says "don't write in your own language".

Comment: @JonathanLeffler for me, it's just experience: You almost never know for sure that you *won't* show the code to someone with a different native language than yours. Think about companies going international, or individuals deciding to open-source some of their code. Well, whatever, it's a side note and meant as a tip only ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need this:

```
...
FILE *archivo;     /* archivo = puntero al archivo clientes.dat */    
abrirArchivo(&archivo);
...

void abrirArchivo(FILE **archivo)
{
  if ( ( *archivo = fopen( "libros.dat", "rb" ) ) == NULL ) {
    ...
}
```

With your solution `archivo` will not be modified after the call to `abrirArchivo(archivo)`.

Comment: I'd think returning the value, such as `FILE *abrirArchivo(void) { ... return( archivo ); }` is probably a lot easier to understand than passing a pointer and dereferencing it.

Comment: @AndrewHenle yes, I agree that returning the value is better, but this answer addresses directly the OPs problem (variable not modified as he expects).

Answer (score 0):

your program is suffering with shadowing global pointers.
try this move the global file pointer to `main`. 
change the `abrirArchivo( FILE *)` function a little. 
one option is as below.

```
//    FILE *archivo;     /* archivo = puntero al archivo clientes.dat */

int main()
{
    FILE *archivo = abrirArchivo( );
    if( arvhivo )
    {
        listar(archivo);
        cerrarArchivo(archivo);
    }
    return 0; /* indica terminación exitosa */
}

FILE *abrirArchivo(){
    FILE *archivo = NULL
    if ( ( archivo = fopen( "libros.dat", "rb" ) ) == NULL ) {
       printf( "El archivo no pudo abrirse" );
    }
    return archivo ;
}
```